Setting up SQL Auth for Azure SQL DB via SSRS
I am referring the below MSFT doc :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/sql-azure-connection-type-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver16
wherein confused with the below statement:
SQL Database supports only SQL Server Authentication (user name and password) and users must provide credentials (login and password) every time they connect to SQL Database.
Does this mean that when the report is published in SSRS server, we would have to share the username and password of the SQL account with all the users?
